# Determine valid iMessage address on a Mac?

Tags: iphone, mac, messages

On my iPhone, I can try messaging someone by tapping on a contact entry or enter a phone number or email address. If the person has iMessage enabled, the text entry field will say "iMessage" instead of "text message", and I'll know if the person can actually receive iMessage.

On my Mac, however, there is no way to tell. I can enter an email address, type in the test and send it, and attempt to send it. If I don't see the status as "delivered", I can guess maybe the other party doesn't have iMessage, but i never know, maybe the person's device is simply off line, or I can wait for a few hours to be sure.

Is there a way to determine whether the address is valid on a Mac like I can on the iPhone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is not an e-mail address registered for the service, it will turn red.

[image]

Additionally, you will get an error message when trying to send the message.

[image]

Comment: i tried sending a msg to an address that does not have iMessage set up, and i did get an error message. however, i tried the same thing several time earlier, and i didn't get any error message. i actually heard the hoofing sound like the msg had been sent.